Entorno virtual en Python
He estado mirando varias web sobre creación de un entorno virtual en python, he entendido su utilidad, permite mantener la instalación del IDLE de Python limpia y evita errores.
Pero a la hora de instalarlo/ usarlo no termino de aclararme. Trataré de explicarme.
Tengo Python 3.12 instalado en c:\Programas\python\python312 y he instalado el entorno virtual en c:\Programas\python\kivy_env y posteriormente lo he activado, todo de forma correcta. Posteriormente he instalado mediante pin install kivy el programa kivy,
El problema es, ¿y ahora que6?. Por que si arranco el IDLE de Python como  hacia hasta ahora no reconoce el entorno virtual, y si entro con la consola de Windows en el entorno virtual y ejecutó el Python del entorno virtual se queda en modo consola de Windows el shell.
¿No puede el entorno virtual la apariencia del.IDLE sin entorno virtual?.  ¿Ha de funcionar en línea de comandos?.
No se si me he explicado correctamente, pero espero que alguien me entienda y me sea explicar / orientar.
Gracias

El IDLE no tiene una forma de establecer el entorno virtual a usar desde una opción gráfica, pero dado que está implementado como un paquete más, enLib/idlelib, lo más simple y portable es ejecutar el IDLE desde una  terminal con el entorno virtual a usar activado.
Es decir:

Abrir una terminal

Activar el entorno virtual
con venv/Scripts/activate, venv/bin/activate, venv/bin/activate.fish, etc dependiendo del SO y shell usada.

Lanzar el IDLE con:
python -m idlelib



En exactamente igual que haces al ejecutar otro paquete/módulo instalado en el entorno, por ejemplo con el mismo pip, ejecutar python -m pip install <paquete> dentro del entorno activado instala el paquete en él.
Puedes hacer lo mismo para ejecutar el IDLE de otro intérprete instalado (sin un VENV), por ejemplo:
py -3.12 -m idlelib

py -3.11 -m idlelib

...

Simplemente se usará el paquete del intérprete ejecutado.
